How can we show $\mathsf{Ext}$ classifies extensions using injective, rather than free, resolutions?
Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring, $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules. Suppose that I have an injective resolution of $$0\to A\to I_0\to I_1\to 0$$ for $A$ and want to construct an extension of $B$ by $A$ using an element of $\text{Ext}(B,A)$. I am a little confused by this process (most literature I have seen uses projective resolutions for this but in my case the injective resolutions are much shorter and simpler).
The injective resolution gives a cochain complex $$0\to\text{Hom}(B,I_0)\to\text{Hom}(B,I_1)\to 0$$ and then $\text{Ext}(B,A)$ is the cokernel of the morphism $\text{Hom}(B,I_0)\to\text{Hom}(B,I_1)$. So we represent our chosen element of $\text{Ext}(B,A)$ by the morphism $f:B\to I_1$. I need to find an $R$-module $X$, a morphism $A\to X$ and a morphism $X\to B$ for which $$0\to A\to X\to B\to 0$$ is exact. What do I do now to construct such an $X$?

First of all, for most rings an injective resolution of length $1$ is not possible; we don't need this assumption. Just let $J$ be any injective container of $A$, and take the cokernel $Q$. $0\to A\to J\to Q\to0$. Now as $\mathsf{Ext}^{>0}(B,J)=0$, we get: $$0\to\hom(B,A)\to\hom(B,J)\to\hom(B,Q)\to\mathsf{Ext}^1(B,A)\to0$$An exact sequence. So any element of the first extension module lifts to a homomorphism $B\to Q$. You can then perform the (dual of the) usual construction; consider the pullback of $J\rightarrow Q\leftarrow B$, call it $X$, and forge the extension $0\to A\to X\to B\to0$.
We have very closely followed the most standard treatments where $B$, rather than $A$, is resolved. We have more or less just dualised that process. Of course, you still have to figure out a way of proving this association of an element of $\mathsf{Ext}^1(B,A)$ with an extension $X$ is well-defined and an isomorphism. The theory is handled rather generally, beyond module categories, sometimes under the name of "Yoneda Ext" (where Ext is modelled as morphisms in the derived category) e.g. in the appendices to Iversen's "cohomology of sheaves".
